# Azure function app create

Tags: azure, jenkins, bitbucket, azure-functions

I´m using ***az functionapp create***  for creating function ap in Azure, where apparts of creating the function app it also hooks it to a bitbucket repo. I´m using parametere ***--deployment-source-url -u*** but it seems is not working this way and is giving me an error. This is done by a jenkin file pipeline

```
node {
stage('Azure Login') {
    withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('6-8afd-ae40e9cf1e74')]) {
        sh 'az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID'
        sh 'az account set -s $AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'
    }
}
stage('Build Azure FuntionApp') {

    sh 'az functionapp create -g $RG_NAME -p $SP_NAME -n grey-$JOB_NAME-$BUILD_NUMBER -s $SA_NAME --deployment-source-url https://  bitbucket.org/xxxx/functions/s***strong text***rc/develop --debug'
}
```

If I put --deployment-source-url -u https://user@bitbucket.org  I get:

---

> ERROR: az functionapp create: error: argument
>   --deployment-source-url/-u: expected one argument

---

I tried without the -u just : --deployment-source-url https://@bitbucket.org

and the job gets done, but the link with bitbucket repos is not made. Getting this:

[image]

So how is it that this work? how come if I put user it says invalid argument and if I don´t it pases but It can find user. Does anyone ever used this command to create a function app?   thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create **azure function** via **azure-cli**, you could change the deployment resource url after `--deployment-source-url`.  You could refer to my command to create **a function with a blob trigger**, replace the url of yours.  It works fine on my side.

**Note**: The **Access level** should be public, you could check it in **Settings** like the screenshot below.

[image]

```
az functionapp create --deployment-source-url https://bitbucket.org/xxx/azure-function --resource-group resourcegroupname --consumption-plan-location westeurope --name joyfun22 --storage-account <storage_name>
```

[image]

Besides, you also can use a **github repository** to create a function.

For example, to use the command below to create **a function with a blob trigger**.

```
az functionapp create --deployment-source-url https://github.com/Joyw1/Azure-Function-Trigger  --resource-group myResourceGroup --consumption-plan-location westeurope --name <app_name> --storage-account  <storage_name>
```

**Update**:

If your Access level is **private**. You need a **access token** to access your bitbucket repository. Please follow the steps bellow.

1.Go to the Bitbucket Labs -> Access Management -> OAuth -> Add consumer

More details, refer to this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html).

2.Enable authenticated git deployment with Azure CLI

```
#!/bin/bash

gitrepo=<Replace with your GitHub repo URL e.g. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-quickstart.git>
token=<Replace with a GitHub access token>

# Enable authenticated git deployment
az functionapp deployment source update-token \
  --git-token $token
```

For complete command, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-create-function-app-github-continuous#sample-script).

Comment: what if this is not a private repo? how can I use key o credential ID for connecting to bitbucket? is this only possible with a public repo?? shouldn´t be

Comment: @Guillermo-Casco I have updated my reply, you could refer to it. Any update let me know, thanks.